# Portable Method Of Converting an int to GLubyte

Tags: c++, opengl, int, type-conversion, valueconverter

Does anyone know of a portable method to convert the value of an `int` to a `GLubyte`? I am not sure where to begin, and I cant seem to find an answer to this :-/

Comment: Why not just cast it?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro It does not seem to do the trick :-( if I print the GLubyte (after putting it into a std::stringstream) it displays NULL, and the GDB reports the value of it to be (it is suppose to be 255) 255 '/377'.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem to the one you are asking here.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro How do you mean (to me it seems like the value is getting mangled)?

Comment: Generally, it is not possible to convert `int` to `GLubyte` because `int` is required to be at least as large as `short`, and `short` is required to be at least 16 bits. `GLubyte` on the other hand, is required to be at least 8 bits. However, if you are certain that the values are in an allowable range, you can simply cast.

Comment: @Damon The values go to a maximum of 255. and I have tried a few different methods of casting: `()`, `static_cast`, etc. but I keep getting the same result, I am really not sure why particularly since the function it is in worked before I changed it to a method and moved it to a different file 0.0 I keep going over the old and new version, but there is essenchailly no difference except variable names.

Comment: Well, of course `std::stringstream` does not display anything meaningful for a `GLubyte` value. That is not an intrinsic data type in C++, it *may* be represented as an `unsigned char` but `std::stringstream` does not know this. Cast it to `unsigned char` or `unsigned int` before trying to output its value to a formatted text stream.